# Double newlines instead of single one

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

Recently i came across a question asked in a coding challenge. task was to process the data in given format and output the correct format. Example, suppose i have array (say words[]) of N strings, each string needs to be printed in a new line, i followed the following approaches:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)cout<<words[i]<<"\n"
```

in C++, and

```
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

in Python. Suppose, the array is:

```
words = ["apple", "mango", "banana"]
```

So the correct output for the above code must be:

```
apple
mango
banana
```

but instead getting the following output:

```
apple

mango

banana
```

Please help me figure out the mistake.

Comment: Could you do a `repr` on the elements in the list `words`. `for word in words:..print(repr(word))` ?

Comment: If that's the actual data and that's the actual code, you can't possibly get that output.

Comment: The code works correctly. If you're getting double newlines it's probably because there's a newline character appended to each string in words.

Comment: Please post actual code along with the actual data you're printing. (Read about what a [mcve] is.)

Comment: Is this a C++ question or a Python question?

Comment: @hansolo still getting the one extra newline in output, i even tried out finding if the strings have any newlines already present, but still the problem exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem with the implementation. Look at the following results from rextester.com.

Python: https://rextester.com/ZPMRZ45393

C++: https://rextester.com/CLB25868

Are you using a linux terminal to output your strings? Are you using an IDE? Check your settings. If you have set your settings in your IDE to automatically create a new line whenever you print a statement, then that's why you see double lines.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have a new line character at the end of each element in your List(array).

you can try the below code

```
for word in words:
    print(word, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code:

```
words = ["apple", "mango", "banana"]
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
apple
mango
banana
```